# Django Channels is not taking over deployment server

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I am attempting Django Channels for the first time. I am following this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cw8-KFVXpTE&t=21s - which basically explains Channels basics. I installed Channels in my virual environment using `pip install channels` and it installed the latest version, which is 4.0.0. I have laid out the basic setup. But when I run `python manage.py runserver`, I get -

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 10, 2023 - 02:37:40
Django version 4.1.3, using settings 'BrokerBackEnd.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

when I shoul be getting this -

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 10, 2023 - 02:37:40
Django version 4.1.3, using settings 'BrokerBackEnd.settings'
Starting ASGI/Channels version 4.0.0 development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

I cannot figure out what I might be doing wrong here and I cannot find any relevant solution anywhere. I would really appreciate any suggestions anyone might have.

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'channels',
    
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',

    'Orders',
]

ASGI_APPLICATION = "BrokerBackEnd.asgi.application"
```

**asgi.py**

```
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
import Orders.routing as route

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'BrokerBackEnd.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': get_asgi_application(),
    
    'websocket': URLRouter(
            route.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
})
```

**consumer.py**

```
class OrderConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()
    
    def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        self.send(text_data="Message = " + text_data)
    
    def disconnect(self, code):
        return super().disconnect(code)
```

**routing.py**

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r"socket/order/", OrderConsumer.as_asgi())
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of [django-channels 4.0.0](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releases/4.0.0.html) the daphne server was [decoupled](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releases/4.0.0.html#decoupling-of-the-daphne-application-server) from the rest of channels.  Now, you need to include [daphne](https://github.com/django/daphne) in your **settings.py** INSTALLED_APPS if you wish to use it.  Include this at the **top** of your installed apps.  The tutorial you are looking at uses an older version of channels.

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'daphne',
    'channels',
    
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',

    'Orders',
]

ASGI_APPLICATION = "BrokerBackEnd.asgi.application"
```

Also, make sure daphne is actually installed:

```
pip install -U channels["daphne"]
```

Comment: Yep, also he is going be looking at changing the run server command, its now a daphne command like this daphne -b 127.0.0.1 -p 8000 django_project.asgi:application